# Send multiple button information through form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with multiple buttons and values. I want to submit which button was clicked when I press the submit button along with the value. I have the code below in a php loop with the questions. The code displays yes and no buttons for each question. I am using jquery to keep the classes active and toggle them (this works fine). My problem is when I submit the form only the questions is submitted via POST, and no data from the buttons pressed. How should I approach this to get the buttons pressed submitted (all buttons have a unique id)?

```
echo' <button type="button" name="yes'.$value[Key].'" id="answerf1" class="lietruth yes" >Yes</button>

 <button type="button" name="no'.$value[Key].'" id="answer1" class="lietruth no" >No</button>

<div id="questions">'.$value[Question].'</div>';
//submit button is after the loop
```

HTML of generated page

```
<div id="Answertoggle16">
<div id="questions-box"><input type="hidden" name="question16" value="Question1"><input type="hidden" name="key"  value="5"><input type="hidden" name="user"  value="truthsandlie"><button type="button" name="yes5" id="answerf1" class="lietruth yes" >Yes</button><button type="button" name="no5" id="answer1" class="lietruth no" >No</button>
<div id="questions">Question1</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="Answertoggle17">
<div id="questions-box"><input type="hidden" name="question17" value="Question2"><input type="hidden" name="key"  value="9"><input type="hidden" name="user"  value="truthsandlie"><button type="button" name="yes9" id="answerf1" class="lietruth yes" >Yes</button><button type="button" name="no9" id="answer1" class="lietruth no" >No</button>
<div id="questions">Question2</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="Answertoggle18">
<div id="questions-box"><input type="hidden" name="question18" value="Question3"><input type="hidden" name="key"  value="25"><input type="hidden" name="user"  value="truthsandlie"><button type="button" name="yes25" id="answerf1" class="lietruth yes" >Yes</button><button type="button" name="no25" id="answer1" class="lietruth no" >No</button>
<div id="questions">Question3</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="Answertoggle19">
<div id="questions-box"><input type="hidden" name="question19" value="Question4"><input type="hidden" name="key"  value="30"><input type="hidden" name="user"  value="truthsandlie"><button type="button" name="yes30" id="answerf1" class="lietruth yes" >Yes</button><button type="button" name="no30" id="answer1" class="lietruth no" >No</button>
<div id="questions">Question4</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="Submit-answer" display: inline-block;"><button type="submit">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see the way the HTML of your complete form is rendered?

Comment: i can link the php loop

Comment: I updated the html in the question

Answer (score 0):

Use `type="submit"` You could set your submit buttons like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="id1" value="value">Submit1</button>
<button type="submit" name="id2" value="value">Submit2</button>...
```

Then you can catch it with `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: If i use submit when i click any of the buttons the form action page loads. 10 answers have to be chosen before information is submitted. Sorry if the question was not clear

Comment: just tried this on each button click the form action loaded

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. Added a hidden div and change that value using javascript functions changeValue1(val) and changeValue2(val).

```
<div id="Answertoggle18">
<div id="questions-box"><input type="hidden" name="question18" value="Question3"><input type="hidden" name="key"  value="25"><input type="hidden" name="user"  value="truthsandlie"><button type="button" name="yes25" onclick="changeValue1('no25')" id="answerf1" class="lietruth yes" >Yes</button><button type="button" name="no25" onclick="changeValue2('no25')" id="answer1" class="lietruth no" >No</button>
<input type="hidden" name="no25" id="no25" value="none">
<div id="questions">Question3</div>
</div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function changeValue1(val) {
var b = val;
    document.getElementById(b).value = "yes";
}

function changeValue2(val) {
var b = val;
    document.getElementById(b).value = "no";
}
//-->
</script>
```