# Submit multiple Button Clicks to Form action

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to submit the buttons pressed in buttons tags to the form action when and only when i click the Next button.

HTML

```
<div id="Submit-answer" display: inline-block;"><button type="submit">Next</button>
    </div>
```

The input tags submit fine via post but the button tag is not sending any form information. Is there any way to get this data to submit? Like a workaround or maybe I am missing something. I need to know if the user clicked yes or no for each div. I am using jquery to toggle the classes active so yes and no cannot be selected at the same time

HTML

```
    <form method="post" action="http://truthsandlie.com/check.php">
    <div id="Answertoggle16">
    <div id="questions-box">
<input type="hidden" name="question16" value="Question1">
<input type="hidden" name="key"  value="5"><input type="hidden" name="user"  value="truthsandlie">
<button type="button" name="yes5" id="answerf1" class="lietruth yes" >Yes</button>
<button type="button" name="no5" id="answer1" class="lietruth no" >No</button>
    <div id="questions">Question1</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Answertoggle17">
    <div id="questions-box">
<input type="hidden" name="question17" value="Question2"><input type="hidden" name="key"  value="9">
<input type="hidden" name="user"  value="truthsandlie">
<button type="button" name="yes9" id="answerf1" class="lietruth yes" >Yes</button>
<button type="button" name="no9" id="answer1" class="lietruth no" >No</button>
    <div id="questions">Question2</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Answertoggle18">
    <div id="questions-box">
<input type="hidden" name="question18" value="Question3">
<input type="hidden" name="key"  value="25">
<input type="hidden" name="user"  value="truthsandlie"><button type="button" name="yes25" id="answerf1" class="lietruth yes" >Yes</button>
<button type="button" name="no25" id="answer1" class="lietruth no" >No</button>
    <div id="questions">Question3</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Answertoggle19">
    <div id="questions-box">
<input type="hidden" name="question19" value="Question4"><input type="hidden" name="key"  value="30">
<input type="hidden" name="user"  value="truthsandlie">
<button type="button" name="yes30" id="answerf1" class="lietruth yes" >Yes</button>
<button type="button" name="no30" id="answer1" class="lietruth no" >No</button>
    <div id="questions">Question4</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Submit-answer" display: inline-block;"><button type="submit">Next</button>
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
jQuery("#Answertoggle10 .lietruth").click(function(){
        jQuery("#Answertoggle10 .lietruth").removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});
jQuery("#Answertoggle11 .lietruth").click(function(){
        jQuery("#Answertoggle11 .lietruth").removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});
jQuery("#Answertoggle12 .lietruth").click(function(){
        jQuery("#Answertoggle12 .lietruth").removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" id="click-next" action="http://truthsandlie.com/check.php">

$( "form#click-next > button" ).trigger( "click" );
```

This will allow the buttons clicked to be submitted to the https://truthsandlie.com/ check.php page ?

**Update below is what I did. Thanks for your help!**

[Send multiple button information through form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238373/send-multiple-button-information-through-form/39241295#39241295)